# Segue not executing

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am having a brain block.  After combing the SO database I am at a loss as to why this segue is not executing. It took me long enough to figure out how to reset my NSUserDefaults. When I finally did, I figured this would work fine. After all, I have set up many segues in my app. Now, this one does nothing.

```
func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()->Bool{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
        println("App already launched")
        return true
    }else{
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
        println("App launched first time")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showEULA", sender: self)
        return false
    }
}
```

The log shows the "App launched first time" text so I would expect the segue to execute.  However, noting happens. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dispatch_async on the main_queue.  call the function in viewWillAppear.

```
func segue() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showEULA", sender: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. Could you point me to a reference where I can learn what the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` command does.  I'd like to understand how this worked for the future.

Comment: Try Apple documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/  -- or -- there's quite a lot of good info on SO about it all.

Comment: Basically, the Cocoa Touch UI-prefix elements want to run on the main queue.  I think your save to defaults was also a factor in the threading.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating the segue? If you put up the code where you're creating the segue or explain how you're creating it in Interface Builder that would help explain why it's not working. It's possible you haven't associated the "showEULA" identifier with the segue.

Comment: I created the segue by control dragging from one VC to the other. I then clicked on the segue in the Main Storyboard and in the utilities pane I click the attributes inspector and enter "showEULA" for the identifier. That is how I have done all of my segues and they all work fine when called by `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Am I missing something?

Comment: where are you calling isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce() ? If you're calling it in viewDidLoad() it might not work properly, try placing it in viewDidAppear() or viewWillAppear()

Comment: Following your advice, I moved the `isAppAlreadyLaunchedOne()` function out of `viewDidLoad()` and created a `viewWillAppear()`.  It looks like this:
 `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()
    }`
I have run the app and I still do not get the segue to execute. I even reset the `NSUserDefaults` in case that was the issue. No joy.

Comment: Here is what I have tried. In the `isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()` function, I have added some `printLn()` messages to be sure the code is getting touched. I also have a `printLn()` message in `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()` just printing that function name. The code is stepping through like this: "View Did Load", "View Did Appear", "App Launched first time", and then, "showEULA". I am just about out of ideas as to why the segue will not execute.

Comment: Here is what the code looks like:
 `func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()->Bool{
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        
        if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
            println("App already launched")
            return true
        }else{
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce")
            println("App launched first time")
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showEULA", sender: self)
            println("showEULA segue")
            return false
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Something needs to own the performSegueWithIdentifier().

Call it from your your initial UIViewController, like

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showEULA", sender: self)
//OR FROM ANOTHER CLASS
refToMainVC.performSegueWithIdentifier(...)
```

Also your user default checking is wrong I think, you are setting a bool but reading a string. You can use boolForKey() instead.

Comment: The `performSegueWithIdentifier` command is in the main VC. With that being the case, do you have any other suggestions?